# Unidirectional many-to-one relation in Doctrine MongoDB ODM without MongoId

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I'm trying to port the following Doctrine ORM example to Doctrine ODM.

```
<?php
/** @Entity */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Address")
     * @JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="address_id")
     */
     private $address;
}

/** @Entity */
class Address
{
    // ...
}
```

I'm looking for the counterpart of @JoinColumn(), which I couldn't find in the documentation. Basically, I want to set the referencing field name and the referenced field name myself. How can I do this?

Comment: ODM references are quite well documented: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/reference-mapping.html Documents are referenced by id only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB you can only reference by id, but you're not limited to using MongoID's. In fact, you can use whatever you like, including objects as id's.

This is what you should do in MongoODM, to have a property of Address act as id and `User` will reference `Address` by the value of that field. You should also set `simple=true` for the reference.

```
/**
 * @Document
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Address", simple=true)
     */
    protected $address;
}

/**
 * @Document
 */
class Address
{
    /**
     * @Id(strategy="NONE")
     */
    protected $someProperty;
}
```

Remember that if you change the value of that property in any of the addresses that are referenced by one or more users, that reference will become corrupt and cause some painful errors in doctrine ODM.

Comment: Just to add my two cents, Mongo doesn't let you modify document identifier once it's set so nothing bad can happen from this. But nothing stops you from removing the `Address` that is referenced though, if such thing happens https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/pull/1336 may help